# Is there any plugin in wordpress that display popular posts when user is about to exit the website?

Tags: wordpress

I found one i.e. Icegram but it does not displays popular posts

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution.
Hope this may be helpful to others.
Install any widget that displays popular posts. Now install another plugin called 'amr shortcode any widget' and then in widget panel drag and drop popular posts widget and then in html of exit popup (eg wBounce) write '[do_widget "*BK: Widget Tabs" ]'.